# correct way to use the constructor with props?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-props

When I print to console, it says that the auth isn't loaded and thus there is no auth.uid. Why?

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            auth : props,
            links : props.auth.uid ? <SignedInLinks /> : <SignedOutLinks />
        };   
    }

...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `this.state`, don't you mean?

```js
auth : props.auth
```

Maybe simpler to define state outside of constructor:

```js
// Inside your component but not inside the constructor:

state = {
  auth : this.props.auth,
  links : this.props.auth.uid ? <SignedInLinks /> : <SignedOutLinks />
};
```

But even so, you're simply inserting your redux state props into your component state.  Why?  Why not just read directly from redux state, like so?

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return this.props.auth.uid ? <SignedInLinks /> : <SignedOutLinks />
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar);
```

Comment: Sounds like that's less an issue with react-redux or any of your `state` and `props` and more of an issue with your firebase.  Does your `state.firebase.auth` exist?  I'm not familiar with firebase but it seems you need to look there to make sure your `.auth` object is what you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was not use "this.state.auth.isLoaded" but instead "this.props.auth.isLoaded". I did not use a constructor or anything.